# HTML Borders Won't Hide

Tags: html, css

I've a series of tables and I'm looking to hide the border but I can't seem to make them disappear.

```css
table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Part 1 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 80%">
      <ul>
        <li style="text-align: left;">Summary</li>
        <li style="text-align: left;">Target</li>
        <li style="text-align: left;">Material</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've added a screenshot of what is being displayed in my browser.
[image]

Comment: There aren't any borders displayed when I run that code.

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: Which browser you are running?

Comment: I can't see any borders in your code

Comment: Google Chrome, Version 56.0.2924.87

Comment: No borders appear in chrome 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again

Comment: See my answer, it appears to be a IDE bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer seems to be that there is a bug in the Dreamweaver `Preview In Browser` feature. When I use this feature the table looks like the image I provided in my original post. When I open the page directly in Google Chrome the borders are indeed hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `!important`

just like this:

```
border: 0px !important
```